# chrome extension: access html of a background tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Basically I want to write a chrome extension to inspect the text (related some kind of status) of an HTML element of a background tab (non-current tab) every a few seconds, and update the extension icon accordingly. Note that I have no control over that webpage. Is that possible to do that? I read a lot of the docs but could not find a way.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether the page is background. Because extension works perpetually, therefore you don't really need to think about that.

If the problem you have is not knowing how to check a text of DOM element every few seconds, this can be done  with [setInterval](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval&ei=eETXUcC1M9GQswbzxoDQBw&usg=AFQjCNFRsptKe74EtFT0ovk5TImkL5Ae-w&sig2=_glBf9LcMgbgw4Gls0kCbg),

```
var interval = setInterval(checkText, 10000): // Run checkText function every ten seconds
function checkText() {
    var el = document.getElementById("elementid");
    if (el.innerText.match(/the text you want to check/)) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: iconPath2});
    }
}
```

And don't forget to put this code into the content script.